# Invalid hook call even if everything is right

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am getting this warning lately every time I'm using hooks, I don't know what to do, I make you sure that none of the stated 3 possible reasons (duplicate react, mismatched version or broken hook rule) holds true but still however I'm getting into this problem

```
const WelcomeScreen = ({ match, location }) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const state = useSelector(state => state.first)
    const id = match.params.id
    const { examDetails, loading } = state;

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getInstituteDetails(id))
    }, [dispatch, id])

    if (loading)
        return <h3>Loading...</h3>
    
    console.log(examDetails);
    return {...
```

It is showing on the second line itself

Comment: Can you make a minimal example in codesandbox? We only can guess that the problem is in other parts of the code. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-bhaskara-9v752?file=/src/App.js   Plz Help @DennisVash

Comment: `render` does not expect a component reference, but a component instance. If you want to pass a reference use the `component` prop instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong API with `react-router-dom`:

```
// not render={WelcomeScreen}
<Route component={WelcomeScreen} path="/" exact />
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-thompson-ujlxf?file=/src/error.js